# Issue with MFI program signup

Tags: web, mfi

I am having issues with the Apple website and their mfi program. How can I solve this issue in the image attached?

[image: MFI program error]

Comment: is the last period necessary?

Comment: @Martheen according to the example that they give yes it is - but I have tried both ways with no success - I am now on the phone with Apple.